# @Autowire Service in doFilter Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am building a project spring boot.

I want call UserService to query get authorities of user. But @Autowire in class JWTFilter not working with UserService and return NULL.

Class SecurityConfiguration

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;

    public SecurityConfiguration(TokenProvider tokenProvider, CorsFilter corsFilter, SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
        this.corsFilter = corsFilter;
        this.problemSupport = problemSupport;
    }

    @Bean
    GrantedAuthorityDefaults grantedAuthorityDefaults() {
        return new GrantedAuthorityDefaults(""); // Remove the ROLE_ prefix
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/content/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
                .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
        .and()
            .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' data:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://storage.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' data:; font-src 'self' data:")
        .and()
            .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
        .and()
            .featurePolicy("geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; fullscreen 'self'; payment 'none'")
        .and()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/students/check-account/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/students/request-active").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/students/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/image").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/websocket/tracker").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/websocket/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .and()
            .httpBasic()
        .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider);
    }
}
```

Class JWTConfigurer

```
public class JWTConfigurer extends SecurityConfigurerAdapter<DefaultSecurityFilterChain, HttpSecurity> {

    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;


    public JWTConfigurer(TokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JWTFilter customFilter = new JWTFilter(tokenProvider);
        http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Class JWTFilter (I want @Autowire UserService here to call getUserWithAuthorities() )

```
/**
 * Filters incoming requests and installs a Spring Security principal if a header corresponding to a valid user is
 * found.
 */
public class JWTFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

    public static final String AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN = "access_token";

    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    public JWTFilter(TokenProvider tokenProvider) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        String jwt = resolveToken(httpServletRequest);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && this.tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
            Authentication authentication = this.tokenProvider.getAuthentication(jwt);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    private String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest request){
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        String jwt = request.getParameter(AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN);
        if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt)) {
            return jwt;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Class UserService

```
/**
 * Service class for managing users.
 */
@Service
@Transactional
public class UserService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private final UserSearchRepository userSearchRepository;

    private final AuthorityRepository authorityRepository;

    private final CacheManager cacheManager;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,
            UserSearchRepository userSearchRepository, AuthorityRepository authorityRepository,
            CacheManager cacheManager) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userSearchRepository = userSearchRepository;
        this.authorityRepository = authorityRepository;
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Optional<User> getUserWithAuthorities() {
        return SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().flatMap(userRepository::findOneWithAuthoritiesByEmailIgnoreCase);
    }
```

Comment: you can annotated `JWTFilter` as `@Component` and see it works or not. let me know.

Comment: @Shoshi  Thanks. I added annotated ```JWTFilter``` as ```@Component```. But not working. @Autowire return null.

Comment: After defining it as Component you have to inject `JWTFilter` to `JWTConfigurer`. don't manually create JWTFilter in JWTConfigurer.
And also in your `SecurityConfiguration` class make `securityConfigurerAdapter()` public. And annotate it with `@Bean`
@TonyTran

Comment: wow, that's great. Did my suggestion work? or you find out something else?

Comment: I added ```@Autowire``` in JWTProvider and it's working. Thanks @Shoshi. A marginal problem, I want to lock the account within a time when the number of wrong logins is too many. What solution do you have for this problem?

Comment: So, where is your `JWTProvider`? I can't see any in the question. 
BTW, you can count the wrong login and put it in redis. when the limit exceeds, then also put the value timestamp of the lock. from here you can check whether the lock time period is over or not.

Comment: Sorry. I forget to provide ```JWTProvider ``` and it's marked with ```@Component```.

Comment: No problem. glad to hear that you find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `@Autowired` annotation requires the class to be a `@Component`. Note that other annotations imply `@Component`, for example a `@Service` is also a `@Component`.

Comment: I tried adding annotation ```@Component``` i but it still doesn't work. Service return null.